# Gaussian distribution with variance involving a discrete random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, summation, random-variables, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Assume  that conditioned on random variable X, $Y$ is a gaussian random variable  as follows:

$\hspace{7cm}Y \sim  \mathcal{N}(0,X+1).$

Here, $X$ is a discrete RV which takes the value $k \times \sigma^2$ with probability$\frac{\binom{N}{k}}{2^N-1-N}$ where $k \in \{2,3,...N\}$.

How can I compute the PDF of $Y$?

**My attempt**: $f_Y(y)=\large\sum_{k=2}^{N}\small f_Y(y|X=x)Pr(X=x)$. But, I am unable to simplify this summation. Can someone help me simplify this? Is there a closed-form expression for the PDF of $Y$?

If it is not directly possible, is there an approximate expression assuming $N >>1$.?

Comment: I don't know how to finish this up, but here's a sketch: I assume that $X + 1$ is the variance of the normal distribution.
$$\begin{align}
f_{Y}(y) &= \sum_{x \in \{2\sigma^2, \dots, N\sigma^2\}}f_{Y}(y \mid x)f_{X}(x) \\
&= \sum_{x \in \{2\sigma^2, \dots, N\sigma^2\}}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-0.5y^2/(x+1)} \cdot \dfrac{\binom{N}{x/\sigma^2}}{2^N - 1 - N} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{(2^N - 1 - N)\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{k=2}^{N}\dfrac{\binom{N}{k}}{\sqrt{k\sigma^2+1}}e^{-0.5y^2/(k\sigma^2+1)}\text{ with }k = x/\sigma^2
\end{align}$$

Comment: @Clarinetist, I am interested in simplifying this summation. Unfortunately, the binomial weights on the Gaussian pdf is preventing me from proceeding further.